# Hygienic macro r7rs : Return second expression value

Tags: scheme, racket, r6rs, define-syntax, r7rs

I'm currently learning some r7rs and I am trying to implement a macro 'begin' as following :

```
(begin0 expr0 expr1 ... expr2)
```

With expr being a regular expression (Like (set! x (+ x 1)))

And begin0 as a macro that evaluates all the expression but return only the expr1 result.

For example :

```
(let ((year 2017))
(begin1 (set! year (+ year 1))
  year
  (set! year (+ year 1))
  year))
```

It musts return 2018

I've created a begin function first :

```
(define-syntax begin0
 (syntax-rules ()
  ((begin-0 body-expr-0 body-expr-1 ...)
   (let ((tmp body-expr-0)) body-expr-1 ... tmp))))
```

And now, I'm trying to understand how I can do to return the value of "body-expr-1" ? 
I've done the following code, but it says that I'm missing some ellipsis and I don't understand how to do it.

```
(define-syntax begin1
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((begin1 body-expr-0 body-expr-1 ... body-expr-2)
     (let ((tmp body-expr-0) body-expr-1 ... tmp)
       (cond (eq? tmp body-expr-1)
              (begin . tmp))))))
```

I hope that it is understandable enough, thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done, but the macro will interfere such that you cannot do all the things with `begin1` as with `begin`.

```
(define-syntax begin1
   (syntax-rules ()
     ((_ expr0 expr1 exprn ...)
      (begin
        expr0
        (let ((result expr1))
          exprn ...
          result)))))
```

The code that does not work is this:

```
(begin1
  (define global1 10)
  test3
  (define global2 20))
```

The reason is obvious. It expands to:

```
(begin1
  (define global1 10)
  (let ((result~1 test3))
    (define global2 20)
    result~1))
```

The second `define` will be changed to a `letrec` such that the variable `global2` is only available for the duration of the `let`. I have no fix for this since it requires you to be able to do global `define` from a closure.

`begin1` is rather strange feature. In Racket and perhaps other Scheme dialects we have `begin0` that returns the result of the first expression. This is very useful. eg. here is a counter:

```
(define (get-counter from)
  (lambda ()
    (let ((tmp from))
      (set! from (+ from 1))
      tmp)))
```

And with `begin0`:

```
(define (get-counter from)
  (lambda ()
    (begin0 
      from
      (set! from (+ from 1)))))
```

In Racket `begin0` is a primitive. So it is a form supported in the fully expanded program and thus implemented in C, just like `begin`..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is exactly what I needed ! 
And many thanks for the explanations, I wasn't understanding how to do it but it seems a lot more clear !

Answer (score -1):

So, I found a possible way to do it, I didn't though we could just ask a condition on the immediate value :

```
(define-syntax begin1
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((begin1 body-expr-0 body-expr-1 body-expr-2 ...)
       (if body-expr-1
          (write body-expr-1)))))
```

Comment: In this you are not evaluating anything else than the second expression. I would assume `(begin1 (display "h") (display "i") (display "!"))` should print "hi!" and the result be `#<undefined>`, but that is not what happens.